# Bootstrap 4 - limit responsivenes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I need to limit responsivenes of my bootstrap project.

lets say we have following element

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">column</div>
```

I need bootstrap to do not resize webstie on .col-sm (website should be resized only on col-lg-4 - show div in 4 columns, and col-md-6 - show div in 6 columns, but than during making more small screen, webiste should stay in the same size and do not any more resize) - it should be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">column</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Remove col-sm-12

Comment: this does not solve issue. because website will be still resizing down. when I resize window. and it should be the same size and should be bigger than window, so it should be scrolled.

Comment: use min-width and min-height

Comment: still not solve issue, because elements are reordered when changing browser size, website should not change.

Answer (score 0):

ok, my solution was to disable responsiveness totally.

I followed example in [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

1. set width of 'container' css class as 972p!important
2. remove from html header
3. changed all col-md-*, col-sm-* and col-lg-* to col-xs-*